# Bootstrap 3 Collapse in other section one per time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have put together a FAQ with categories. My idea is to use the function Collapse bootstrap to display each category and into the collapse see a accordion with questions and answers.

It is structured in two columns on the left select the category and the right questions and answers.

I need to select a second category (collapse) the previous close.

I could build up here.

```
<div class="container">
  <section id="tratamientos" class="row">
    <h1>Tratamientos</h1>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cirugiaoral" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="cirugiaoral">Cirugía Oral</button>
      <br><br>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#blanqueamiento" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="blanqueamiento">Blanqueamiento</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      
      <div class="collapse" id="cirugiaoral">
        <h3>Cirugía Oral</h3>
        /* FAQ with accordion */
        <ul>
          <li>item with accordion</li>
          <li>item with accordion</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <div class="collapse" id="blanqueamiento">
        <h3>Blanqueamiento</h3>
        /* FAQ with accordion */
        <ul>
          <li>item with accordion</li>
          <li>item with accordion</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

[Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/g4UZD0vTOZ)

Comment: Do you mean just like an accordion? If so see [Bootstraps Accordion Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)

Comment: @Ted I need to do in two columns, you would use the accordion would have an accordion inside another accordion and that is bad for the user. please look at the example in bootply

Comment: ahh...missed the bootply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this script:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $('.collapse').not(e.target).removeClass('in');
});
```

That'll hide the other sections for you when a scection is shown

See this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/A8Gr3ya256)